# Cannot copy and paste older version of code in Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

In Eclipse with the SVN plugin Subclipse. When I right click on a file and go

```
Team --> Show History
```

Then I select a version of the file I want to view,. All commands like Select all (Ctril-A) , copy (Ctrl-C) and paste (Ctril+V) do not work.

Is this some sort of protection feature to stop people using older versions of the code?

My latest version of code is badly broken, I want to replace it with the contents of an older file version?

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the file and choose 'Replace with->Revision or URL' then choose a working version and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why Eclipse doesnt let you copy, paste etc?

Comment: This eclipse behaviour is pretty annoying also for me; anyway, if you want to copy just a portion of the file, drag the selection with the mouse e.g. in a folder (using Ubuntu) and you will have a file with what you want..

Answer (score 1):

From the History view, the option you would want in your scenario is Get Contents.  This will take the contents of the file in the selected revision and replace the contents of the file in your working copy with it.  The file will then likely show as Modified locally and you could edit/commit as desired to update the HEAD revision with those changes.